# Google Drive API: I have to fetch only files in that folder without trashed files

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to get a list of files in a folder on Google drive using the Google drive API.    When I make my request I am getting a list of child elements in that folder including previous deleted files.

How do I get only the files that are in the folder without the ones that have been deleted or trashed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you are seeing deleted files.  Deleted files are permanently [deleted](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/delete).   I think you are seeing [trashed](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/trash) files which are like putting files in the trash can on windows, they are removed but not really gone.

You want to add a [search parameter](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters) to your [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) request.   you want to tell it to not include trashed.

> trashed = false

Comment: Yes those are thrashed files, later i could resolve the issue by adding this piece of code,

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and i added this piece of code to resolve the issue,

```
Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File fileDetails = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File();
 try
 {
    fileDetails = service.Files.Get(fileId).Fetch();
   //check whether files is in thrash and ignore if any
    if (fileDetails.Labels.Trashed.GetValueOrDefault())
     {
          return null;
     }

  }
```